# Openlayers not rendering on QGIS 2.8

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I uninstalled QGIS and removed all files on the computer with QGIS in them. I then reinstalled version 2.8. I still get the same problem that google streetmaps does not display. When I try one of the other options in the openlayers plugin I get this.

[image]

These little question marks suggest a problem with the graphics of this layer. How do I get Openlayers working?

EDIT: UPDATE: It works on a home pc not at work which has a proxy. We have tried fiddling with the proxy but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it wasn't a proxy issue because it was working previously. Turns out the user I was asking this question for had changed his password. The solution was to update proxy settings.

Feel free to remove this question or mark it as a duplicate because I know there are other questions regarding proxies.

I'll leave it to the admins to decide.